# DLLRegisterServer failed

Tags: ocx, regsvr32, depends

I was trying to re-register .ocx file that is included in my project. I got this error message:

DllRegisterServer in XXXX.ocx failed.
Return code 0x8007007e.

I have run depends.exe and nothing seems wrong with the dependency. I only saw question mark icons beside "IESHIMS.dll" and "WER.dll" which I believe can be ignored. And "MPR.dll" gets a red coloured box. These errors are ignorable based on DependencyWalker FAQs. 
Other than that, everything is fine.

I have run the registration with administrator right as well.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Are there any related messages in the Event Viewer?

Comment: How do you check the Event Viewer? Sorry newbie here. Thanks.

Comment: It is in Administrative Tools. Look in System and Application logs if there are any errors for the time when the ocx registration failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for not updating this question for long time. I got help from my friend and it works fine now. And I think I update the question and hope that this will be useful for other people.

All errors or red-colored box in DependencyWalker can be ignored, they are just windows files. The registration failed because my ATL.dll is actually pointing to ATL from other software (let say software A), not from C:\windows\system32\atl.dll.

Software A replaces the C:\windows\system32\atl.dll with their own version of ATL.dll (which is not good). Uninstalling software A did not help. What I did was go to registry key, check the path of ATL.dll, change it to C:\windows\system32\atl.dll, and register the ATL.dll.

After that I tried to register my .ocx and it works.

Hope this will be useful for other people!

Thanks.